# PyQt5 window not showing properly in pycharm interactive console

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, pyqt5, python-interactive

I can't run qt interactively in pycharm 2021.3.2, which is quite annoying.

For example, if I run in the pycharm console:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
window.resize(400, 300)
button = QPushButton("Click Me!", window)
window.show()
```

A "blank" (non responsive) windows appears.

When I run `app.exec_()` in the console, the windows is showing properly, and I can play with the widgets, but then the console is blocked, and I can't open an close windows without crashing qt.

This exact behaviour shows up also when using qt backend for matplotlib. In a normal console (outside of pycharm), no problem.

For now I only found a temporary fix for matplotlib by using TK backend.
Any solution ?

PS: I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know about PyCharm, but on normal interactive interpreters PyQt installs an "input hook" (see ["Using PyQt5 from the Python Shell"](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/python_shell.html). I don't know if you can install an input hook if it's not already present, but try with [`QtCore.pyqtRestoreInputHook()`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtcore/qtcore-module.html#pyqtRestoreInputHook).